# any tools for making UI-based or email-based DEADLINE notifications in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

Are there any tools for making UI-based or email-based DEADLINE notifications in org-mode?

It'd be nice to convert org-mode's pull-based DEADLINE access (via C-c a a) into a push-based system :)

Comment: `C-c a a` isn't a binding in vanilla org mode

Comment: That would likely require a timer (with auto-repeat perhaps) and the org-mode buffer(s) would need to be opened (at least in the background) when that timer goes off, and then integrate that to something like Wanderlust.  Doable, but non-trivial.  It could also be integrated to create a system notification -- e.g., when timer buzzes and deadline within range exists, than run an applescript on OSX that plays a song or speaks a message or whatever.  Emacs would need to be running, or a system based timer to launch Emacs.

Comment: I think it is more than doable. Which is why I thought maybe someone already did it :)  All you need to do is point the notifier code at the files to watch, and show them how to parse out the DEADLINE sections.

Comment: The simplest solution is doing it in an agenda hook. I assume you use agendas. When an agenda is bult it shows the tasks with deadlines, so in a hook fuction after the agenda is ready you parse the agenda buffer and if there are any deadlines then you send a notification. You can store in a file which notifications have been sent already, so they are not sent twice.

Comment: The following link is for cross-reference purposes because the two threads are (in my opinion) closely related to one another:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3844/2287  It's not necessary to use an agenda buffer (since all that is needed is an re-search-backward [from point-max] of the raw master todo *.org file), but a list to keep track of previous notifications is indeed important as Tom indicated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this indirectly by exporting your org files to icalendar with `C-c C-e c a` and loading the resulting ics file in Thunderbird or Google Calendar or some other calendaring tool.   Most such tools can give notifications about deadlines.

For Thunderbird, import the file as a "on the network" calendar with a url of `file:///path/to/calendar.ics`.