# change warning time on a per appointment basis

Tags: org-mode, appt

I use `appt` to remind me of my upcoming appointments (which I keep in an `org-mode` file).  Under this setup, my computer beeps five minutes before the beginning of the next appointment (see setup [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3844/good-methods-for-setting-up-alarms-audio-visual-triggered-by-org-mode-events)).

Is there a way change the warning time on a per-appointment basis? (e.g., if I have a meeting in a different building I would like to set up a 20-minute warning; for most other meetings, a 5-minute warning is fine).

I imagine nice solutions to this would be:

- Including the warning time in the `org-mode` timestamp (e.g., `<2016-07-12 Tue 16:15-20>` would mean beep 20 minutes before the meeting), or
- Associating a tag to a given warning time (e.g., items tagged `:far:` would beep 20 minutes before the meeting).

Any ideas on how to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 2):

You want the `APPT-WARNTIME` property, I think. See section "Appointment Reminders" at the bottom of:

```
(info "(org) Weekly/daily agenda")
```

For properties:

```
(info "(org) Properties and columns")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   Alt x appt-add
   Time  (hh:mm[am/pm])
   Message
   Minutes before the  appointment
```

to start warning