# Org-mode calendar notifications on Windows 10

Tags: org-mode, message, notifications

I'm looking for a way to have emacs send me desktop notifications (on Windows 10) for appointments in my org file. I did find a way to be notified within emacs (https://sachachua.com/blog/2007/11/setting-up-appointment-reminders-in-org/) and also how to have a desktop notification on Mac (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-02/msg00644.html ) and also on Linux ([Good methods for setting up alarms (audio + visual) triggered by org-mode events?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3844/good-methods-for-setting-up-alarms-audio-visual-triggered-by-org-mode-events?newreg=b1361afaeb3c40d3bccfcceea37d80fe) ) but not on Windows. Can anyone help me with that maybe through Windows native message boxes or Autohotkeys? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution buried in this video:
https://vimeo.com/16533939 
It uses a visual basic code that popups up a message showing the title of your event.
Here's the VB code (I put it in a file named PopUp.vbs):

```
On Error Resume Next
Msgbox wscript.Arguments(0),0,"Agenda Reminder"
```

and here's the configuration needed in your .emacs or .spacemacs file (you need to modify the path to the VB file accordingly):

```
;; Enabling the "appt" Windows notifier
  ;; https://vimeo.com/16533939
  ;; Get appointments for today
  (defun my-org-agenda-to-appt ()
    "Rebuild all appt reminders"
    (interactive)
    (setq appt-time-msg-list nil)
    (run-at-time "24:01" nil 'my-org-agenda-to-appt)
    (let ((org-deadline-warning-days 0))
      (org-agenda-to-appt)))

  ;;; Disabled so that I can open multiple emacs without org loading agenda files
  (appt-activate t)

  ;; 5 minutes warning
  (setq appt-message-warning-time '60)
  (setq appt-display-interval '15)

  ;; Update appt each time agenda is opened
  (add-hook 'org-finalize-agenda-hook 'my-org-agenda-to-appt)

  ;; Setup agenda popup, we tell appt to use window, and replace default function
(setq appt-display-format 'window)
(setq appt-disp-window-function (function my-appt-disp-window))

(defun my-appt-disp-window (min-to-app new-time msg)
  (save-window-excursion
    (shell-command
     (concat
      "c:/Windows/System32/cscript.exe //nologo c:/Dropbox/ToDo/PopUp.vbs \"" msg "\"")nil nil)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but here is what I use.
For alerts, I use the [alert package](https://github.com/jwiegley/alert), for which you can define custom notification styles.
On the below snippet, I defined one to use the built-in *w32-notification-notify*

```
(use-package alert
  :config
  ;; Add the windows desktop notifications if on windows
  (when (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (alert-define-style
     'windows-desktop-notification-style
     :title "Windows Desktop Notification style"
     :notifier
     (lambda (info)
       (let ((notif-id (w32-notification-notify :title (plist-get info :title) :body (plist-get info :message))))
         ;; Close it after 3 seconds (no new notification can be sent if left unclosed)
         (run-with-timer 3 nil `(lambda() (w32-notification-close ,notif-id))))))
    (setq alert-default-style 'windows-desktop-notification-style)))
```

To be reminded of everything in my org agenda, I use the [org-alert](https://github.com/spegoraro/org-alert) package (which conveniently uses alert under the hood)

```
(use-package org-alert
  :demand  ; Load it on startup, not lazily
  :config
  (org-alert-enable))
```