# emacs org: how to set alarm to appointment

Tags: org-mode

I'm wondering how can I set a sound alarm 'n' hour before an appointment. Today, I've lost my second appointment. I saw it just the time the appointment is set

thank you

### Renato

yes!!! I've finaly found it!
It's the DEADLINE statement.
DEADLINE:<2024-02-04 Sun 16:15>
wrote after my issue "** bla bla bla" tell to orgzly (the program I use to read the .org I have) to signal the issue, emitted a beep!
it’s what I’m looking for

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3844/good-methods-for-setting-up-alarms-audio-visual-triggered-by-org-mode-events

Comment: See also [Org FAQ](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#automatic-reminders) and [Org Hacks](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html#org-agenda-appt-zenity) on Worg. [Worg](https://orgmode.org/worg/) is a useful source of information (even though some articles may be outdated).