# Appt desktop notification system for org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, linux

I'm on Linux and I've been trying to set up a reliable notification system.

E.g I have a task like this:

```
* TODO submit weekly report
  SCHEDULED: <2014-03-04 WED 16:30>
```

I would like a *reliable* notification to appear at 16:30, preferably a lib-notify one.

Thus far, I have read and tried:
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/5806
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/5271
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToDoChiKu

I had a little bit of success with ToDoChiKu, in the sense that I had a notification pop up on a scheduled event, but it didn't seem to come up for every scheduled event. e.g when I rescheduled a task a new reminder didn't pop up.

Does anyone have a working notification system that they would be willing to share? (linux)

**[EDIT]**
I got something semi-functioning going. I had wrong configs in my warning and interval timings and my hooks weren't working well.

In all of the examples, the appt-time-msg-list was updated in different situations. For one guy when he saved his file, for another when he reloads (but not loads) the agenda etc.. 
By merging all hooks, I made it more reliable.

I'll test-drive my solution for a couple of days and if it works well I'll post in here.

But if you have a working solution, please feel free to post.

Comment: Here are a couple of related threads:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3844/good-methods-for-setting-up-alarms-audio-visual-triggered-by-org-mode-events and http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/any-tools-for-making-ui-based-or-email-based-deadline-notifications-in-org-mode